# Buffer overflow example not working on Debian 2.6

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, stack-smash

I am trying to make the buffer exploitation example (example3.c from http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) work on Debian Lenny 2.6 version. I know the gcc version and the OS version is different than the one used by Aleph One. I have disabled any stack protection mechanisms using -fno-stack-protector and sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0 arguments. To account for the differences in my setup and Aleph One's I introduced two parameters : offset1 -> Offset from buffer1 variable to the return address and offset2 -> how many bytes to jump to skip a statement. I tried to figure out these parameters by analyzing assembly code but was not successful. So, I wrote a shell script that basically runs the buffer overflow program with simultaneous values of offset1 and offset2 from (1-60). But much to my surprise I am still not able to break this program. It would be great if someone can guide me for the same. I have attached the code and assembly output for consideration. Sorry for the really long post :)

Thanks.

---

```
// Modified example3.c from Aleph One paper - Smashing the stack
void function(int a, int b, int c, int offset1, int offset2) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
   int *ret;

   ret = (int *)buffer1 + offset1;// how far is return address from buffer ?
   (*ret) += offset2; // modify the value of return address
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int x;
  x = 0;
  int offset1 = atoi(argv[1]);
  int offset2 = atoi(argv[2]);
  function(1,2,3, offset1, offset2);
  x = 1; // Goal is to skip this statement using buffer overflow
  printf("X : %d\n",x);
  return 0;
}

-----------------
// Execute the buffer overflow program with varying offsets
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=60; i++))
do
   for ((j=1; j<=60; j++))
   do
    echo "`./test $i $j`"
   done
done

-- Assembler output
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x080483c2 <main+0>:    lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
0x080483c6 <main+4>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x080483c9 <main+7>:    pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
0x080483cc <main+10>:   push   %ebp
0x080483cd <main+11>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080483cf <main+13>:   push   %ecx
0x080483d0 <main+14>:   sub    $0x24,%esp
0x080483d3 <main+17>:   movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080483da <main+24>:   movl   $0x3,0x8(%esp)
0x080483e2 <main+32>:   movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
0x080483ea <main+40>:   movl   $0x1,(%esp)
0x080483f1 <main+47>:   call   0x80483a4 <function>
0x080483f6 <main+52>:   movl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080483fd <main+59>:   mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048400 <main+62>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048404 <main+66>:   movl   $0x80484e0,(%esp)
0x0804840b <main+73>:   call   0x80482d8 <printf@plt>
0x08048410 <main+78>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x08048415 <main+83>:   add    $0x24,%esp
0x08048418 <main+86>:   pop    %ecx
0x08048419 <main+87>:   pop    %ebp
0x0804841a <main+88>:   lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
0x0804841d <main+91>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) disassemble function
Dump of assembler code for function function:
0x080483a4 <function+0>:    push   %ebp
0x080483a5 <function+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080483a7 <function+3>:    sub    $0x20,%esp
0x080483aa <function+6>:    lea    -0x9(%ebp),%eax
0x080483ad <function+9>:    add    $0x30,%eax
0x080483b0 <function+12>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
0x080483b3 <function+15>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x080483b6 <function+18>:   mov    (%eax),%eax
0x080483b8 <function+20>:   lea    0x7(%eax),%edx
0x080483bb <function+23>:   mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x080483be <function+26>:   mov    %edx,(%eax)
0x080483c0 <function+28>:   leave  
0x080483c1 <function+29>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disassembly for `function` you provided seems to use hardcoded values of `offset1` and `offset2`, contrary to your C code.

The address for `ret` should be calculated using byte/char offsets: `ret = (int *)(buffer1 + offset1)`, otherwise you'll get hit by [pointer math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605772/1233508) (especially in this case, when your `buffer1` is not at a nice aligned offset from the return address).

`offset1` should be equal to `0x9 + 0x4` (the offset used in `lea` + 4 bytes for the `push %ebp`). However, this can change unpredictably each time you compile - the stack layout might be different, the compiler might create some additional stack alignment, etc.

`offset2` should be equal to `7` (the length of the instruction you're trying to skip).

---

Note that you're getting a little lucky here - the `function` uses the `cdecl` calling convention, which means the caller is responsible for removing arguments off the stack after returning from the function, which normally looks like this:

```
push arg3
push arg2
push arg1
call func
add esp, 0Ch ; remove as many bytes as were used by the pushed arguments
```

Your compiler chose to combine this correction with the one after `printf`, but it could also decide to do this after your function call. In this case the `add esp, <number>` instruction would be present between your return address and the instruction you want to skip - you can probably imagine that this would not end well.

Comment: Thanks for your input Dcoder. I tried the values of offset1 and offset2 but it didn't work :( I have a very fundamental question though. If I try to solve this using the brute-force approach isn't there supposed to some offset1, offset2 for which it should yield X=0 i.e. skip X=1 statement. I don't understand why I am not able to get it working even through the brute-force approach. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @invinc4u: can you provide the compiled binary, so I can look at it in more detail?

Comment: The issue was because of the pointer math that you were referring. Once I modified the code as suggested by you ret = (int *)(buffer1 + offset1) , the code worked fine for me. Thanks a tonne for all your guidance :)