# Seg Fault during pointer manipulation

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have the following struct in C.

```
struct a {
    long state;
    long uid;
    long w, x, y, z, xx, yy, zz, xxx, yyy, zzz;
    char comm[64];
};
```

Then I do a `malloc` as follows.

```
buf = malloc (100 * sizeof(struct a));
```

But when I try to access the individual structs as follows, I get a seg fault.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    tmp = buf + (i * sizeof(struct a));
    printf ("\t>%d>%ld,%ld\n", i, tmp->state, tmp->uid);
}
```

I am getting a seg fault after the first 10 entries. I have no idea why this happens. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605745/c-pointer-math-with-structures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if buf is a pointer to a struct a, the pointer math should be:

```
tmp = buf + i;
```

Comment: but I dont understand how this works, dont we have to increment the point by the sizeof(struct). 
Lets buf is at location 100, and the sizeof(struct a) is 50, so the next struct will be at 150 right. but if we do (buf + i) wont it increment by just 'i' places, eg, if i=1, and buf=100, then buf+1 will give 101 right..

Comment: look at AusCBloke's detailed answer.

Comment: also, probably not at 150 on your 32bit or 64bit machine, since the struct address will be word aligned by default.  Again, look at AusCBloke's answer and trust in your compiler to do the pointer math correctly based on struct size, word alignment, padding, yada yada yada

Answer (score 4):

This line is wrong:

```
tmp = buf + (i * sizeof(struct a));
```

You don't need to multiply `i` by the size of each element in the array, this is done implicitly for you based on the type of `buf`.

What you're actually doing is

```
tmp = &buf[i * sizeof(struct a)];
```

when what you're really trying to do is

```
tmp = &buf[i];
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler already handles `sizeof()` advancement during pointer arithmetic. Thus,

```
ptr + i;
```

is the same as

```
&ptr[i];
```

It is **wrong** to use

```
ptr + (i * sizeof(some_type));
```