# Wrong result with sizeof

Tags: c, debugging

I have here a really weird issue:

```
typedef struct        s_mem_chunk
{
  void                *addr;
  unsigned int        size;
  short               is_alloc;
  struct s_mem_chunk  *prev;
}                     t_mem_chunk;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  t_mem_chunk *mem_chunk;

  mem_chunk = malloc(sizeof(*mem_chunk));
  mem_chunk->prev = 0;

  printf("%x + %x = %x\n", mem_chunk->prev, sizeof(*mem_chunk), mem_chunk->prev + sizeof(*mem_chunk));
  return 0;
}
```

So the code here should output:
"0 + 18 = 18"
And it output instead "0 + 18 = 240"

So I am wondering why, this is may cause by the sizeof ot I dont know...
I request your help, thanks in advance for your time and have a nice evening ! :D

Comment: a pointer doesn't really know the size of what it is pointing at.  the correct method to get the size would be: 'sizeof(t_mem_chunk)'

Comment: Pointer math is not the same as integer math. For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605772/1233508).

Comment: @user3629249: `sizeof(*mem_chunk)` is a perfectly valid way to obtain the size of the type pointed to by `mem_chunk`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense: `sizeof(t_mem_chunk) == 0x240/0x18 == 0x18 == 24`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misinterpreted 0 + 18 = 240 which is the right result!

0 is the value of `mem_chunk->prev`.
18 is the size of your structure; beware that this is in hexa.

You have **pointer arithmetic**, so `mem_chunk->prev + sizeof(*mem_chunk)` is not 0+18 as usual but the address of an hypothetic 19-th element of an array starting at 0. So 0x18*0x18=0x240 in hexa. In pointer arithmetic, adding a number to a pointer calculates a move; the `int` serves as a distance from the pointer, and units for the distance is the type of objects the pointer points to. If you add 1 to an `int` pointer, you calculate the memory address *one `int` after*...

In your case:
`mem_chunk->prev+1` is not `1` but `0x18` and `mem_chunk->prev+2` is not `2` but `0x30`.

Also pay attention to the format and use `%p` for pointers and `%lx` (`%zx` in C99) for sizeof which returns a `long int`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your advices, now I know what really happens here :)

Comment: `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, for which the length modifier (C99, afair) is `z` (as in `%zx`).

Answer (score 2):

Your program invokes undefined behavior.

`x` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `unsigned int` but `mem_chunk->prev` is a pointer value. Same for `mem_chunk->prev + sizeof(*mem_chunk)` which does not perform integer arithmetic but pointer arithmetic and yields an invalid pointer.